# Как проверить, что элемент массива удовлетворяет условию?

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм, .net, инспекция-кода

У меня есть задание:

> Implement an FilterByDigit method that obtains an array of integers whose elements contain a given digit. Don't use LINQ. The task definition is given in the  XML-comments for this method.
> For example, for array { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 68, 69, 70, 15, 17 } => { 7, 70, 17 } for digit = 7.
> Topics -  arrays, arithmetic operations.

Короче говоря, в методе нужно вернуть массив, который состоит из тех элементов данного массива, в котором содержится конкретная цифра.

Вот мой код, который я написал, как его можно улучшить?

Может быть я могу использовать `Array.FindAll`?

```
namespace FilterTask
{
    public static class ArrayExtension
    {
        public static bool IsContainDigit(int element, int digit)
        {
            if (element == 0 && digit == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            element = Math.Abs(element);
            while (element != 0)
            {
                if (digit == element % 10)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                element /= 10;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static int[] FilterByDigit(int[]? source, int digit)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            }

            if (source.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid size");
            }

            if (digit < 0 || digit > 9)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(digit));
            }

            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (IsContainDigit(source[i], digit))
                {
                    ++count;
                }
            }

            int[] answer = new int[count];
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (IsContainDigit(source[i], digit))
                {
                    answer[j++] = source[i];
                }
            }

            return answer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Если это "расширение" (а судя по названию класса да), то где `this` у метода `FilterByDigit`? Если это не расширение, то странное название, да и статика тогда тут не нужна. 2. В случаях, когда мы что-то перебираем и возвращаем наружу, на помощь приходит "ленивый перебор", который реализуется через `yield return`. Ну и 3, мне кажется вы много всего сделали лишнего, например вот [вся ваша логика](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LzBg6N) в несколько строк кода, без лишних массивов, проверок, и прочего.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ подозреваю что если Linq использовать нельзя, то и итераторы тоже.

Comment: @aepot В моем понимании "не использовать LINQ" это не делать `var result = array.Where(x=>...);`. Но тут уже автору виднее.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ автор вырезал XML комментарии метода, но подозреваю что сигнатуру метода не он придумал. А чтобы получить массив на выходе, потребуется либо Linq `.ToArray()`, либо цикл. Так что без лишних массивов не выйдет. Между прочим, у автора минималка по памяти, но не по скорости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код в целом хороший.

Для начала, можно немножко упростить поиск цифры. Поменяю названия элементов там, где считаю нужным.

```
private static bool ContainsDigit(int number, int digit)
{
    if (number == digit)
    {
        return true;
    }

    number = Math.Abs(number); // а надо ли это?
    while (number != 0)
    {
        if (digit == number % 10)
        {
            return true;
        }

        number /= 10;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Здесь для производительности ещё можно `Math.DivRem` прикрутить, но не буду усложнять.

Далее, у вас двойной проход. Из условия не ясно, можно ли модифицировать исходный массив. Допустим, можно.

Уберу обработку исключений для простоты ответа.

```
public static int[] FilterByDigit(int[] source, int digit)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
    {
        int number = source[i];
        if (ContainsDigit(number, digit) && j != i)
        {
            source[j++] = number;
        }
    }
    Array.Resize(ref source, j);
    return source;
}
```

Итого, с использованием ровно такого же объёма памяти, но в 2 раза быстрее.

Если исходный массив модифицировать нельзя, то придётся сделать копию, например с помощью `Array.Copy`. А можете или нет использовать `FindAll` - вам решать, ну или тому, кто дал вам эту задачу.